# blessdiff for the "full featured hexadecimal editor"?

Tags: diff, ascii, hex

I am trying to find some hex diftool which allows me to compare to documents in the view but also the internal differences like in `bless` so two bless windows side-by-side but with diff capability between the windows, at least for selection. 
I find the `bless - A full featured hexadecimal editor` could be the best choice here for the integration.

Is there any difftool for hex-ascii view in any Linux distro?

Comment: Checkout http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/how-can-i-use-vim-as-a-hex-editor - and with vim's split view you're done.

Comment: @ott-- I opened a new thread about starting `vimdiff` in such a condition: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4022/2923

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to view changes, not edit them, you can convert the files to hex with one program and then diff the output with any graphical diff program you want. It is probably only practical if there are only changed (not inserted) bytes between the files.

As a one-liner:

```
meld <(hexdump -C file1.bin) <(hexdump -C file2.bin)
```

And here's a screenshot of 2 different copies of libssl.so on my system:
[image: hexdump | meld]

Comment: Meld is ok with small files. Bless is with both. Selection of 200Mb and 20 Mb file to compare does not show any similarities because Meld is loading still the 200 Mb file, in different way than does bless.

Comment: Too heavy operation for meld

Answer (score 1):

If your files could have inserts/deletions, you can use this command to diff:

```
meld <(xxd -c 1 -ps file1.bin) <(xxd -c 1 -ps file2.bin)
```

Comment: Command works fine; there's however a stray `-C` in it.

Comment: @NZD Thanks! Fixed